# Flutter - Hide hint text when Text Field have focus

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to know how to hide the hint text when I focus on the text field. This is my code:

```
class _ContactoState extends State<Contacto> {
  FocusNode focusMsj;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    focusMsj = FocusNode();
    focusMsj.addListener(() {
      if (!focusMsj.hasFocus) {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusMsj);
      }
    });
  }

TextField(
          focusNode: focusMsj,
            hintText: focusMsj.hasFocus ? ' ' : 'Hint Text',)

return WillPopScope(
          child: Listener(
            onPointerUp: (e) {
              focusMsj.hasFocus ? FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()): '';
            },
```

Thank you

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For doing that matter you need to make something like that

```
class Play extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlayState createState() => _PlayState();
}

class _PlayState extends State<Play> {
  FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
  String hintText = 'Hello , iam Hint';
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (focusNode.hasFocus) {
        hintText = '';
      } else {
        hintText = 'Hello , iam Hint';
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        print(focusNode.hasFocus);
      }),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              focusNode: focusNode,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: hintText,
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: '!!',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Shortly i listened to TextField by its focusNode property . When TextField  has focus i make hintText property equal empty String value

Comment: also you should dispose focuseNode.     focusNode.dispose();

Answer (score 18):

There is a property for that:

```
TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hasFloatingPlaceholder: false));
```

> **Edit**: The version above is deprecated, the new version is:

```
TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,),),
```

Comment: @floe This does not hide hint text

Comment: Hi @SardorbekRkh can you maybe post your problem, for me and other guys it works.

Comment: This affects the floating label, while the question was about the hint text.

Comment: This does not hide hint text, the question was about the hint text

Comment: Doesnt hide hint text...

Comment: Hi guys! To use this feature just use labelText instead of hintText and set `alignLabelWithHint` to `true`. So labelText will be appear as hintText and with `floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never` it will be hided as soon as field would be focused. Full example in separated answer

Answer (score 6):

Simply, don't add the `hintText` in the `InputDecoration` and mention only the `labelText: 'Label'` alongside `labelStyle` if you want to change the ***style*** of the label.

```
TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Label",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
        ),
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
    )
)
```

Comment: this one should be the verified answer

Answer (score 5):

One simple solution you can try is define labelText with FloatingBehavior.never

```
TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Search",
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
    )
)
```

HintText will be shown when it is not focussed. On focus, hint text will disappear.

Comment: This technically works unless you want to have a floating label...

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is there is no way to implement it without custom code. Hiding hintText when focused with "border: InputBorder.none," gives perfect login widget example as FloatingLabelBehavior and having animated labelText just won't do. floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never - helps in some situtations but not the exact thing we wanted. If you have labelText and hintText FloatingLabelBehavior.never is helpful to control hiding and showing hintText and animating labelText above the field. WIth custom code we have

```
String emailHintText = "E-mail";
```

on the  top of state class. Then:

```
Container(
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
             child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child:      

    Focus(
          onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                        setState(() {});
                        emailHintText = "";
                      } 
                else {
                        setState(() {});
                        emailHintText = "E-mail";
                      }
                    },
          child: TextFormField(
                     decoration: InputDecoration(    
                                    hintText: emailHintText,
                                    border: InputBorder.none))));
```

Now, you should know that using setState is a bit costly operation and may not be the best option if not used for very important functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me. Just add on InputDecoration ( floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never) of TextField or TextFormField.

`TextFormField( controller:_controller, decoration : InputDecoration( label: Text('Entrer your code here '), floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never, ), );`

Answer (score 0):

One more answer, but with some clarifications. As in some other answers, you can use `floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never` to achieve this.

But for this feature you need to use `labelText` instead of `hintText`. This property has other appearance place then `hintText`, but it can be fixed by
`alignLabelWithHint` property. So full example here:

```
TextField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
       labelText: ...,  // your label-hint text
       labelStyle: ..., // your label-hint textStyle
       floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
       alignLabelWithHint: true,
   ),
),
```

Or you can use custom widget instead of default label:

```
TextField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
       label: ...,  // your label-hint widget
       floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
       alignLabelWithHint: true,
   ),
),
```

[image: Result]